# Convert PHP bidimensional array to multidimensional

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a bidimensional array like this:

```
$myarray = [
  ['earth', 'europe', 'paris', 'tour eiffel'],
  ['earth', 'europe', 'rome', 'colosseum'],
  ['earth', 'europe', 'rome', 'roman forum'],
  ['earth', 'europe', 'rome'],
  ['earth', 'europe', 'paris', 'arc de triomphe'],
  ['earth', 'north amercica', 'usa', 'new york', 'empire state building'],
  ['earth', 'north amercica'],
  ...
]
```

and I want to convert it in a multidimensional array like this:

```
$myMultiArray = [
  'earth' => [
    'europe' => [
      'paris' => ['tour eiffel', 'arc de triomphe']
      'rome' => ['colosseum', 'roman forum']
    ],
    'north america' => [
      'usa' => [
        'new york' => ['empire state building']
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I've tried different approaches, and the only one that seems to work is the following:

```
$data = [];
foreach($myarray  as $index=> $el)
{
  if ($index == 0 )
  {
    if (!isset($data[$el]))
    {
      $data[$el] = [];
    }
  }
  else if ($index == 1)
  {
    $data[$myarray[0]][$el] = [];
  }
  // ... etc
}
```

but this can not be an elegant solution, I think

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: is there every time 4 items arrays?

Comment: No, @splash58, the dimension of the original array is variable, can be 1-n.

Comment: You sure that can be 1!?

Comment: It might be an idea to show the code that created the original array and mod that to do what you actually want rather than fiddle with the array later.

Comment: With the current information I would say that using a recursive function would solve your problem.

Comment: I'm getting the data from an external source, and there is no way get it in a different form

Comment: This is not a question. It's a to-do list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cant work when subarraya are  with lenght 1

```
$res = [];

foreach($myarray as $item) {
   $p = &$res;
   for($i=0; $i < count($item)-1; $i++) {
      if(!isset($p[$item[$i]])) $p[$item[$i]] = [];
      $p = &$p[$item[$i]];
      print_r($res);
      }
   $p[] = $item[$i];
}

print_r($res);
```